Get Current Progress from URLSession.shared.dataTask does not work in React Native UI calling to Swift
I'm trying to track the download progress of file with task.progress.obeserve, in PlayGround everything works correctly:

While in React Native, when calling from React Native UI to swift code, it does not invoke task.progress.observe:

@objc(downloadFileFromGoogleDrive:authHeader:savedEncryptedFileUri:withResolver:withRejecter:)
func downloadFileFromGoogleDrive(uri: String, authHeader: String, savedEncryptedFileUri: String, resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    guard let url = URL(string: uri) else {
        reject("Invalid URL", nil, nil)
        return
      }

      var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
      urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
      urlRequest.setValue(authHeader, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    print("================================================")
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data, response, error in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            reject("request failed", error?.localizedDescription, error)
          return
        }

        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            reject("download failed", String(describing: response), nil)
          return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
          reject("no data received", nil, nil)
          return
        }


        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: savedEncryptedFileUri)
        do {
            try data.write(to: url)
            resolve(true)
        } catch {
            reject("cannot load data", String(describing: response), nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    let observation = task.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { progress, _ in
      print(progress.fractionCompleted)
    }
    
    task.resume()
}


I have to keep the observation in class var:
var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-key-value-observing-in-swift
